# VB.NET upload SQL script to create database and tables

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, create-table

I have written a small application. On first run of the application I want to upload an SQL script to the local SQL Server Express Instance.

On my development machine I have created the database and tables and have exported the scripts using SSMS to a sql file. I can import that file into SSMS and execute it, and the database will be created. I do not know how to perform the same process using VB.NET

I added the sql file to my project as a resource and I have included the first few lines below

```
USE [master]
GO
/****** Object:  Database [MyProject]    Script Date: 5/04/2016 11:30:42 PM ******/
CREATE DATABASE [MyProject]
 CONTAINMENT = NONE
 ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'MyProject', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\MyProject.mdf' , SIZE = 4160KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 1024KB )
 LOG ON 
( NAME = N'MyProject_log', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\MyProject_log.ldf' , SIZE = 1040KB , MAXSIZE = 2048GB , FILEGROWTH = 10%)
GO
ALTER DATABASE [MyProject] SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 110
GO
IF (1 = FULLTEXTSERVICEPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled'))
begin
EXEC [MyProject].[dbo].[sp_fulltext_database] @action = 'enable'
end
GO
ALTER DATABASE [MyProject] SET ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT OFF 
...

...
USE [MyProject]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[SomeTable]    Script Date: 5/04/2016 11:30:42 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SomeTable](
    [Identifier] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
....
```

I then used the below code to upload the SQL to the database

```
Private Sub Create_SQL_Database()
    Dim connetionString As String = "Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Trusted_Connection=YES"

    Dim cnn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connetionString)
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand()
    Try
        cnn.Open()
        Console.Writeline("Connection Open ! Attempting to create database")
        cmd.CommandText = My.Resources.CreateDatabaseSQL
        cmd.Connection = cnn
        Try
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Error - " & ex.Message)
        End Try
```

This did not work and I received a lot of errors in a messagebox - **Incorrect syntax near 'GO'** followed by **Database 'MyProject' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.**

I tried removing all of the lines containing GO but was still left with the error - **Database 'MyProject' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.**

I am no expert on this matter but It would seem to me that the GO commands will commit the changes to the database. Because I have been removed the lines with GO on them when the script reaches this line

```
USE [MyProject]
```

the database does not exist because the previous steps have not been committed.

What do I need to do in VB.NET to be able to upload this file to the database and create my database and tables?

Thanks.

Comment: `GO` is not valid SQL.  It is an instruction that is only usable in SSMS and some similar products.  In order to execute it from .NET you'll need to split the code on the `GO`s into separate batches.

Comment: As a general rule, creating a database programmatically is not advisable. Some users may not have "create" database privileges. In some shops, only a DBA can create databases, therefore, you may consider just supplying the script.

Comment: Came back to mark answer but cannot as there is only comments. I split the code as per siyual. Thanks.

Comment: Tom, I agree with your message but in this case I know the users will have permissions.